# AngularJS ng-options to get selected option from an array that matches another scope var

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, default-selected

I have an array and a var

```
$scope.fcFeedTypes = [{"name":"Plain Text","value":"Plain Text"},{"name":"MQ Message","value":"MQ Message"}];
}
$scope.feedEditor.ft = "MQ Message"; // this is dynamically obtained from some other source
```

I want a dropdown select with default selection based on the value of `$scope.feedEditor.ft`

#### HTML:

```
<select ng-model="fcFeedTypes"
        ng-options="ft.name for ft in fcFeedTypes"
        ng-init="ft=feedEditor.ft">
```

I am new to AngularJS and need some help...

Comment: Why are you setting the model to the options array? That doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the string "MQ Message" (or the `value` of whatever a user selects) as your ng-model value, then it's quite simple:

```
<select ng-model="someModelName"
    ng-options="ft.value as ft.name for ft in fcFeedTypes"
    ng-init="someModelName=feedEditor.ft">
```

If you want the full object as the ng-model value, then you've got to find the right one in JS. It must be referentially/strictly equal to the one in the options.

```
<select ng-model="someModelName"
    ng-options="ft.name for ft in fcFeedTypes">
```

-

```
$scope.fcFeedTypes = [{"name":"Plain Text","value":"Plain Text"},{"name":"MQ Message","value":"MQ Message"}];

$scope.feedEditor.ft = "MQ Message"; // this is dynamically obtained from some other source

angular.forEach($scope.fcFeedTypes, function(feedType){
  if(feedType.value === $scope.feedEditor.ft){
    $scope.someModelName = feedType;
  }
});
```

Comment: Great this works! thanks I was a bit confused with ng-model